# Accessing nested Soap elements with pysimplesoap

Tags: python, xml, soap

The Soap function has the following request structure:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/serial_number_information">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ser:Update>
     <ser:Serial_Number_Information>
        <ser:Key></ser:Key>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ser:Item_No></ser:Item_No>
        <ser:Serial_No></ser:Serial_No>
        <ser:Tip></ser:Tip>
     </ser:Serial_Number_Information>
  </ser:Update>
```

I'm trying to send a pysimplesoap request to the function above but I can't seem to get to Serial_Number_Information

```
client.Update(Key=r_key,Serial_No=r_srl,Item_No=n_item,Tip=n_tip)
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to drop pysimplesoap and go the urllib2 direction.  I was getting inconsistent authentication issues with pysimplesoap against the API that is using NTLM+AD on the backend.  Plus I can construct my SOAP calls to explicitly match the structure of the exposed functions.  Yes it's a little more work, but it works consistently.